# Почему после 10% символ % удваивается?

Tags: python, progress-bar

````
import sys
x = 40
a = x-1
per = 0
for i in range(x):
    if i != 0:
        per = a/x
        per = per*100
        per = round(per)
    print('['+'-'*i+' '*a+']'+str(per)+'%' , end='\r')
    a-=1
    sleep(.1)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this code. Symbol `\r` just move the pointer to 1st position, but not clear the screen. Second `%` symbol remains after the previous output

Попробуйте этот код. Символ `\r` просто сдвигает указатель на начальную позицию, но не очищает экран. Второй символ `%` остаётся от предыдущего вывода (10%)

```py
import sys
from time import *

x = 40
a = x-1
per = 0
for i in range(x):
    if i != 0:
        per = a/x
        per = per*100
        per = round(per)
    print('['+'-'*i+' '*a+']'+str(per) + '% ', end='\r')
    a-=1
    sleep(.1)
```

> Result

Результат:

```
[---------------------------------------]0%
```

Comment: Правки моего английского приветствуются)